# Mole - What are the outcomes for allow, execute and fire options?

Tags: phantom-doctrine

Apparently there is a mole in my team that is revealed on chapter 5:

[image: Mole options]

What are the outcomes for allow, execute and fire options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Allow this**: Danger decreases and agent gets loyal perk
  [image]
- **Too risky**: Agent go dark and leaves you
- **Execute**:
  Agent dies